# how to combine two integer columns in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to combine 2 column values having integers with a '_' between them and set it as my index column to my output dataset. 'ID' will be my index.

Sample Data:

[image: inp]

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import io

data = '''
ID,Ang,1
23,0,0.88905321
23,10,0.962773412
23,20,1.004187813
23,30,1.008301223
105,0,0.334209544
105,10,0.39043363
105,20,0.434241204
105,30,0.460348427
47,0,0.020669404
47,10,0.032299446
47,20,0.050602654
47,30,0.073371391
'''
df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data),index_col=0)
```

Expected Output:

[image: out]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Convert index and column to strings and join by `_`, also [`DataFrame.pop`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pop.html) is used for extract column, so then `drop` is not necessary:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(str) + '_' + df.pop('Ang').astype(str)
```

Or  use [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html):

```
df = df.set_index(df.index.astype(str) + '_' + df.pop('Ang').astype(str))
```

---

```
print (df)
               1
23_0    0.889053
23_10   0.962773
23_20   1.004188
23_30   1.008301
105_0   0.334210
105_10  0.390434
105_20  0.434241
105_30  0.460348
47_0    0.020669
47_10   0.032299
47_20   0.050603
47_30   0.073371
```

If want also index name `ID` set `df.index.name`:

```
df.index = df.index.astype(str) + df.pop('Ang').astype(str)
df.index.name = 'ID'
```

And for second solution use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (df.set_index(df.index.astype(str) + '_' + df.pop('Ang').astype(str))
        .rename_axis('ID'))
print (df)
               1
ID              
23_0    0.889053
23_10   0.962773
23_20   1.004188
23_30   1.008301
105_0   0.334210
105_10  0.390434
105_20  0.434241
105_30  0.460348
47_0    0.020669
47_10   0.032299
47_20   0.050603
47_30   0.073371
```

EDIT:

If there are floats with `.0` values, first try converting to integers:

```
df.index = (df.index.astype('int').astype(str) + '_' + 
            df.pop('Ang').astype('int').astype(str))
```

If not working converting to integers, then one possible reason are missing values:

```
print (df)
        Ang         1
ID                   
23.0    0.0  0.889053
23.0   10.0  0.962773
23.0   20.0  1.004188
23.0   30.0  1.008301
105.0   0.0  0.334210
105.0  10.0  0.390434
105.0  20.0  0.434241
105.0  30.0  0.460348
47.0    NaN  0.020669
NaN    10.0  0.032299
47.0   20.0  0.050603
NaN     NaN  0.073371
```

One possible solution for pandas 0.24+ is use [integer na](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/integer_na.html) by convert to `Int64`:

```
df.index = (df.index.astype('Int64').astype(str) + '_' + 
            df.pop('Ang').astype('Int64').astype(str))

print (df)
                1
23_0     0.889053
23_10    0.962773
23_20    1.004188
23_30    1.008301
105_0    0.334210
105_10   0.390434
105_20   0.434241
105_30   0.460348
47_nan   0.020669
nan_10   0.032299
47_20    0.050603
nan_nan  0.073371
```

Or replace missing values to some integers, e.g. `-1` and then convert to integers all values:

```
df.index = (df.index.fillna(-1).astype('int').astype(str) + '_' + 
            df.pop('Ang').fillna(-1).astype('int').astype(str))

print (df)
               1
23_0    0.889053
23_10   0.962773
23_20   1.004188
23_30   1.008301
105_0   0.334210
105_10  0.390434
105_20  0.434241
105_30  0.460348
47_-1   0.020669
-1_10   0.032299
47_20   0.050603
-1_-1   0.073371
```

Comment: For my output df.. I am getting float values in my ID column. Eg. ```23.0_0.0```, ```23.0_10.0``` and so on...How can I omit the decimal places?

Comment: @aXaY - Can you check if working `df.index = df.index.astype(int).astype(str) + '_' + df.pop('Ang').astype(int).astype(str)`?

Comment: yes. Now it works perfectly. issue solved. ```df.index = df.index.astype(int).astype(str) + '_' + df.pop('Ang').astype(int).astype(str)``` worked fine.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
# this is only needed as you set index_col = 0
df = df.reset_index()

# you could keep the columns by removing the call to drop
df = df.set_index(df[['ID', 'Ang']].astype(str).apply('_'.join, axis=1)).drop(['ID', 'Ang'], axis=1)

print(df)
```

**Output**

```
               1
23_0    0.889053
23_10   0.962773
23_20   1.004188
23_30   1.008301
105_0   0.334210
105_10  0.390434
105_20  0.434241
105_30  0.460348
47_0    0.020669
47_10   0.032299
47_20   0.050603
47_30   0.073371
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this, using `set_index` and list comprehension with f-string (Python 3.6+ required):

```
df = df.set_index('Ang', append=True)
df.index = [f'{i}_{j}' for i, j in df.index]
df.index.name = 'ID'
print(df)
```

Output:

```
               1
ID              
23_0    0.889053
23_10   0.962773
23_20   1.004188
23_30   1.008301
105_0   0.334210
105_10  0.390434
105_20  0.434241
105_30  0.460348
47_0    0.020669
47_10   0.032299
47_20   0.050603
47_30   0.073371
```